# How to change xmodem blocksize from 128k to 1024k in vbscript or VBS with SecureCRT command SendXmodem

Tags: vbscript

Using SecureCRT terminal with these commands. When the script executes the SendXmodem to push the file it always defaults to the smallest 128k block size. SecureCRT is able to push files with 1024 block sizes (Xmodem-1K) from the GUI interface commands but I want to automate it in the vbs script. Any way in the vbs script to tell xmodem to switch to 1024k? All sessions in SecureCRT are set to 1024k.

This command runs on the Cisco switch and readies the Cisco switch to receive the file.

```
crt.Screen.Send "copy xmodem: flash:c3750-advipservicesk9-mz.122-25.fz.bin" & chr(13)
```

This command runs on the windows PC serving the file pushed to the Cisco switch.

```
 crt.FileTransfer.SendXmodem("C:\Users\NEW USER\Desktop\IOS\c3750-advipservicesk9-mz.122-25.fz.bin")
```

Copy time at 128k is about 2 hours and 1024k is 25 minutes. This is to recover a switch which has a lost or corrupted software. Older Cisco switches are only layer 2 so no layer 3 TCPIP available for newer/faster protocols.

Tried to modify the command SendXmodem with flags like /B 1024 or /Blocksize 1024

crt.FileTransfer.SendXmodem

Answer (score 2):

Options for a SecureCRT session are stored in `.ini` files found within the "Sessions" subfolder of SecureCRT's configuration folder (**Options / Global Options**, **Configuration Paths** category).

Searching through a SecureCRT session configuration `.ini` file for the term "XModem", you'll find an option named "XModem Send Packet Size" on a line that looks like this, by default:

```
D:"XModem Send Packet Size"=00000000
```

If you edit your session options and enable the **1024 bytes (Xmodem-1k/Ymodem-1k)** option in the **Terminal / X/Y/Zmodem** category, apply that change, and then refer to the refreshed contents of the corresponding .ini file you should see that the same line ends in a `1`.

SecureCRT's scripting API is documented within SecureCRT's built-in help. Take a look at the **Scripting / Script Objects Reference** chapter, specifically the **SessionConfiguration Object** topic. There are a few examples of both VBScript and Python code showing how to use both `GetOption` and `SetOption`.

Specific to the objective you're trying to accomplish, the code would look like this...

**Python:**

```
crt.Session.Config.SetOption("XModem Send Packet Size", true)
```

**VBScript:**

```
crt.Session.Config.SetOption "XModem Send Packet Size", True
```

To disable the option, the code would look like this:

**Python:**

```
crt.Session.Config.SetOption("XModem Send Packet Size", false)
```

**VBScript:**

```
crt.Session.Config.SetOption "XModem Send Packet Size", False
```

Please note that `crt.Session.Config` *always* refers to the configuration associated with the session related to the tab/tile in which the script is running. This means that if you established your connection using something like this (Python)...`objTab = crt.Session.ConnectInTab(strMyConnInfo)`, then you would need to use the `objTab` reference instead of `crt`.

For example: `objTab.Session.Config.SetOption("XModem Send Packet Size", true)`

Comment: You are the man!  I edited the Default.ini as you said and it is working great. This converts all SecureCRT/VBS "xmodem" commands into "xmodem-1k". Even when I changed individual sessions and then all my sessions globally to 1024k via the GUI I still only got 128k. Here is the location of the Default.ini file for future readers.                                                                                                           C:\Users\NEW USER\AppData\Roaming\VanDyke\Config\Sessions\Default.ini (W10)

Comment: @C4C You should mark this as the answer. BTW jdev is from VanDyke technical support. I emailed them and sent a link to this question and he was kind enough to post an answer.